# Failure in connecting to SQL Server Workflow Manager Configuration

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, ssl, sql-server-2012, workflow-manager

So I am Configuring workflow manager 1.0 using the wizard. When I test connection of SQL Server Instance, I receive a red error "Failure in connecting to SQL Server". I am using "machine name\instance name"

I have the Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance checked (as per the guide). When I uncheck the box and test connection, everything passes successfully.

Any ideas? I tried creating a certificate on sql server computer, and enabled it in the sql server configuration manager, and restarted the service.  But I don't know what to do with the certificate.